# Ansible: allocating an elastic ip to newly created instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am creating a new instance with ansible and want to associate an elastic ip to it. What value should i write in instance_id? instance_id: "{{ newinstance.instances[0].id }}" ??? But this value seems to be wrong, because i have an output after checking:

```
TASK: [Allocating elastic IP to instance]     *************************************
fatal: [localhost] => One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'instances'

---
- name: Setup an EC2 instance
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

    - name: Create an EC2 machine
      ec2:
        aws_access_key: my_access_key
        aws_secret_key: my_secret_key
        key_name: my_key
        instance_type: t1.micro
        region: us-east-1
        image: some_ami
        wait: yes
        vpc_subnet_id: my_subnet
        assign_public_ip: yes
      register: newinstance

    - name: Allocating elastic IP to instance
      ec2_eip:
        aws_access_key: my_access_key
        aws_secret_key: my_secret_key
        in_vpc: yes
        reuse_existing_ip_allowed: yes
        state: present
        region: us-east-1
        instance_id: "{{ newinstance.instances[0].id }}"
      register: instance_eip
    - debug: var=instance_eip.public_ip

    - name: Wait for SSH to start
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ newinstance.instances[0].private_ip }}"
        port: 22
        timeout: 300
        sudo: false
      delegate_to: "127.0.0.1"

    - name: Add the machine to the inventory
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ newinstance.instances[0].private_ip }}"
        groupname: new
```

What should i put instead "{{ newinstance.instances[0].id }}"? The same question is about "{{ newinstance.instances[0].private_ip }}".

Comment: Can you add ``- debug: msg="{{ newinstance }}"`` after the ``Setup an EC2 instance`` task? That will show the structure of what was registered. It's also a good idea to state which version of Ansible you're running, to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically trying to parse data from the JSON output of Ansible task which is given to your variable. instance_ids is an array and child of newinstance JSON. Similarly private_ip is a direct child of newinstance

```
---
- name: Setup an EC2 instance
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

 - name: Create an EC2 machine
   ec2:
    aws_access_key: my_access_key
    aws_secret_key: my_secret_key
    key_name: my_key
    instance_type: t1.micro
    region: us-east-1
    image: some_ami
    wait: yes
    vpc_subnet_id: my_subnet
    assign_public_ip: yes
  register: newinstance

- name: Allocating elastic IP to instance
  ec2_eip:
    aws_access_key: my_access_key
    aws_secret_key: my_secret_key
    in_vpc: yes
    reuse_existing_ip_allowed: yes
    state: present
    region: us-east-1
    instance_id: "{{ newinstance.instance_ids[0] }}"
  register: instance_eip
- debug: var=instance_eip.public_ip

- name: Wait for SSH to start
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ newinstance.private_ip }}"
    port: 22
    timeout: 300
    sudo: false
  delegate_to: "127.0.0.1"

- name: Add the machine to the inventory
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ newinstance.private_ip }}"
    groupname: new
```

Comment: when running the `ec2_eip` task, I get a warning `instance_id is no longer used, please use device_id going forward`, there is no mention of `device_id` at the [module docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_eni_module.html) though...

Comment: why do you wait for ssh to become available on `newinstance.private_ip` ? wouldn't it make more sense to wait for it on `newinstance.public_ip` ?

Comment: when running the `wait_for` task, I get an error `Unsupported parameters for (wait_for) module: sudo [...]`, maybe the parameter was removed after the answer was posted...

Comment: also, instead of `newinstance.private_ip` (or `newinstance.public_ip` as mentioned in my earlier comment), what probably should be used is `newinstance.instances[0].private_ip` (or `newinstance.instances[0].public_ip`); again, the answer might have been correct at the time it was posted and the structure might have changed with a new Ansible version

Comment: Rahul: mind if I change your answer so it works with current Ansible versions ?

Comment: Please go ahead